# Loop optimization in Pytorch

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, pytorch

I'm trying to find a way to prevent a painfully slow for loop in Pytorch. Basically, I have a tensor, and I want to split it up into pieces and feed those pieces into my model, similar in spirit to a grouped convolution of sorts.

```
        self.C = C
        self.block = Block(C, 3, 64)
    def forward(self, x):
        x_shape = x.shape
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1, end_dim=-1).unsqueeze(1)
        x = torch.split(x, self.C, -1)
        attention = []
        for i in x:
            attended = self.block(i)
            attention.append(attended)
        attention = torch.stack(attention, 1)
```

Small values of C, alongside a large tensor, I think, makes this operation surprisingly much slower, due to the Python for-loop the above code runs through. However, when I exchange the batch dimension for a 'C' dimension and loop through the batch dimension instead, this causes significant speedups, however still feels hacky to me, and might still prove to be slow with a large enough batch size. I'd like a method to fix this while still keeping the batch-dim intact and avoiding the for loop. What I guess I'm looking for is a method to add a second batch dimension to my model, or something equivalent.

Is there any way to fix this issue other than the slightly-hacky method described above?

EDIT:
MWE: (Pretend like the single linear layer is something like a split Attention layer...)

```
import torch

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, split_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.split_size = split_size
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(split_size, split_size)
    def forward(self, x):
        #Slow implementation:

        #Input is B,C,H and is flattened to B,C*H.
        y = x.flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)

        y_split = torch.split(y, self.split_size, 1) #Tensor is split and each piece is fed into the model...

        outs = []

        for i in y_split:
            i_out = self.linear(i)
            outs.append(i_out)
        y = torch.cat(outs, 1)
        print(y.shape)

        #Fast implementation using batch dims, but possibly slower for large batches...
        y = x.flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
        y_split = torch.split(y, self.split_size, 1)

        y = torch.stack(y_split, 0)
        outs = []
        for i in torch.split(y, 1, 1):
            i_out = self.linear(i.squeeze(1)).unsqueeze(0)
            outs.append(i_out)
        y = torch.cat(outs, 0)
        y = y.flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
        print(y.shape)
        return y
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    net = Net(32)
    net(torch.randn(256,3,32,32))
    net(torch.randn(32,3,32,32))
```

Comment: Can you add an MWE so that we can understand your problem better? Also, that would help  to see the set of operations clearly and may be people would suggest ways that won't even need for loops

Answer (score 0):

I think 2D input will be processed in each channel with the same network layer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).